# Minimization of the loss function in soft-margin SVM

Tags: svm

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), the goal of the soft-margin SVM is to minize the hinge loss function:

$$\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \max \left(0,1-y_{i}\left(\vec{w} \cdot \vec{x}_{i}-b\right)\right)\right]+\lambda\|\vec{w}\|^{2}$$

Could you tell me more why we add $\lambda$? What is its effect on the minimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of $\lambda$ in that equation is to serve as a regularization term (helping to avoid [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)) which determines the relative importance of minimizing $\Vert w \Vert^2$ w.r.t. minimizing $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max(0, 1-y_i(w\cdot x_i - b))$.

By minimizing $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max(0, 1-y_i(w\cdot x_i - b))$ we are looking forward to correctly separate the data and with a *functional margin* $\geq 1$, otherwise the cost function will increase. But **minimizing only this term may lead us to undesired results**.

This is because in order to separate the samples correctly, the SVM may overfit the dataset. This usually leads to higher values of $\Vert w \Vert^2$ due to the increasing [complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting#Machine_learning) needed to fit the whole dataset correctly.

To prevent this, we add a regularization term $\rightarrow \lambda\Vert w \Vert^2$. By doing this, we are not only penalising the fact that the *functional margin* is $<1$, but also high values of $\Vert w \Vert^2$.

However, we should not minimize $\Vert w \Vert^2$ indefinitely, because by doing this we are reducing the capacity of the SVM to fit the data $\rightarrow$ we may end up with the opposite problem than before i.e. underfitting the dataset.

**So, to sum up,** a good balance between minimizing $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\max(0, 1-y_i(w\cdot x_i - b))$ and minimizing $\Vert w \Vert^2$ needs to be met and this why $\lambda$ is used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So is it similar to the Ridge penalization?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ridge penalization but looking at this post from [Statlec](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-statistics/ridge-regression)  it seems that the objective of both regularization terms is the same. Both penalize high values of $\Vert w \Vert^2$ ($\Vert b \Vert^2$ in the linked web) to avoid overfitting and $\lambda$ is the parameter which balances the relative importance of the terms in the cost function.

Comment: When it comes to soft margin SVM, people often mention the introduction of a slack variable $ξ$ for each $x$. In the above loss function, can I interpret $1-y_i(w\cdot x_i - b)$ as $ξ$?